# Nodejs + mongodb + dynamic $set without declaring a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image]

I have been using this method to update the object dynamically, is there any way I can do this without setting up a variable like I do with query?

This is what I am currently using:

```
var query = {}
query["settings.panels."+req.params.type+"."+req.params.id] = req.body

mongoPool.collection('settings').updateOne(
    {_id: req.user.profile.id},
    { 
      $set: query,
    (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: false, returnData: doc }
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: true, errorMsg: 'Db Error',   errorCode: 405 })
    }
})
```

This is what I want:

```
mongoPool.collection('settings').updateOne(
    {_id: req.user.profile.id},
    { 
      //notice I didnt use query & this returns an array
      $set: ["settings.panels."+req.params.type+"."+req.params.id] : req.body
    }, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: false, returnData: doc }
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: true, errorMsg: 'Db Error',   errorCode: 405 })
    }
})
```

Instead it returns an array

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using Node.js 4.x or above, you can use its ES6 support for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to do this:

```
mongoPool.collection('settings').updateOne(
    {_id: req.user.profile.id},
    { 
      $set: { ["settings.panels."+req.params.type+"."+req.params.id]: req.body }
    },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: false, returnData: doc }
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(200).send({ errorStatus: true, errorMsg: 'Db Error',   errorCode: 405 })
      }
    }
)
```